# Why is an extra, manual page load always required in Firefox for Greasemonkey/uBlock Origin to kick in?

Tags: windows-10, firefox, firefox-extensions, firefox-profile

I have some shortcuts to open Firefox, like this:

```
"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" -p "Twitch profile" --no-remote "https://www.twitch.tv/directory/game/somegame"
```

When I run that shortcut, Firefox opens with my "Twitch profile" and opens the URL "https://www.twitch.tv/directory/game/somegame". So far, so good.

However, I have a bunch of elements blocked with the Firefox extension **uBlock Origin** as well as a custom **Greasemonkey** script to make the Twitch chat rooms tolerable. These never "kick in" on this initial page load; I always have to manually reload the page for them to "activate".

This is consistent behaviour. It doesn't just happen sometimes; it always happens. I don't understand it.

I no longer even bother trying to report bugs to Mozilla or trying to get support from them, because they have consistently shown that they just don't care. However, this particular issue at least appears to be a real bug and not intentionally malicious. Nevertheless, it is equally annoying!

What could be causing this? And more importantly: is there a solution/work-around?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like it could be a caching issue. When you load the page, Firefox on start, it's loading whatever elements it already has in your cache.

There is an option in Firefox to clear your cache upon exit. Try enabling that and see if that helps.